# Value '@' in CNAME DNS Record

Tags: dns

After importing godaddy records into AWS Route 53 I saw this CNAME Record

```
site.com        A       Simple  -   71.71.71.71
www.site.com    CNAME   Simple  -   @
```

So what confuses me is **@** value for the CNAME, and www alias didn't work. I had to replace **@** with the actual IP (71.71.71.71) in the example above so the alias would work.

What is this value?

Answer (score 3):

All that is saying, is use the record for site.com to lookup the address.

`@` is used as a variable reference in the zone file for SOA and NS recs, and is replaced with the origin name (the FQDN for the zone) when the zone is loaded. Note that the value of a CNAME rec must be a Name, not an IP. I assume you changed it to an A rec before setting it to the IP you mention.

So the line is saying, that `www.site.com` is an CNAME for `site.com.`.

More info here: https://www.slashroot.in/what-dns-zone-file-complete-tutorial-zone-file-and-its-contents (see the SOA section for info on the variable expansion).